# LINQ: Get all pairs from a dictionary where pair.key is in a string array

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone help me translate this to LINQ?
I have a string array (step.Variables), a dictionary (Parameters) and I want all pairs in Parameters where the key is in step.Variables.

This code works but I want to use LINQ and I cannot figure out how to translate:

```
parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (string variable in step.Variables)
{
    if (Parameters.ContainsKey(variable))
    {
        parameters[variable] = Parameters[variable];
    }
}
```

This is my best guess but get exeption:

```
var parameters = Parameters.ToDictionary(pair => step.Variables.Contains(pair.Key.ToString())).Select(pair => pair);

"System.ArgumentException: 'An item with the same key has already been added.'":
```

Comment: Consider using ReSharper if you can. It will translate any loops to LINQ, where possible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If I understand well, what you need is this:

```
var parameters = Parameters.Where(p=>step.Variables.Contains(p.Key))
                           .ToDictionary(p=>p.Key,p.Value);
```

You need to filter first the `Parameter` dictionary to see if the key is in the `Variables` collection and convert the result, which is `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>>`, into a `Dictionary<string, string>`

Answer (score 0):

Filter out the `Parameters` dictionary if key exists in `step.Variables` then transform it to Dictionary.

```
var parameters = Parameters.Where(p => steps.Variables.Contains(p.Key)).ToDictionary(p => p.Key);
```